# ¿Como MOSTRAR un PDF traido de JAVA en HTML-JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, java

Necesito MOSTRAR un pdf que llega desde JAVA.

Eso lo hago con un servlet.

```
function descargarCarta(){
console.log("entra a descargar");
           var settings = {
               "async": true,
   "crossDomain": true,
   "url": "http://localhost:8080/StaffingApp/accesoServlet?resource=reporteCartaLaboral&codigoVinculacion=00959158-01-TL",
   "method": "GET"
   }

   $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
   });
}
```

asi lo envio del servlet

```
byte[] reporteCarta = null;
reporteCarta = generarReporteCartaLaboral(request, response);
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
response.reset();
String codigo = request.getParameter("codigoVinculacion");
System.out.println("codigo" + codigo);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"Carta_Laboral_" + codigo + ".pdf\"");
servletOutputStream.write(reporteCarta);
servletOutputStream.close();
```

Y a se genera como pdf, pero necesito mostrarlo como PDF en un poryecto HTML

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Tienes el código, sin el es muy difícil ayudarte Saludos....

Comment: @Villegas Ya recibo el arreglo de bytes como puedo convertirlo en un pdf para descargarlo posteriormente?

Comment: Si deseas que te ayudemos debes proveer un [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc con eso basta? es mi codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es obtener un archivo, simplemente desde el servidor seteas el tipo de contenido de la respuesta y envias el contenido:

```
public void download() throws IOException {
    // Prepare.
    byte[] pdfData = getItSomehow();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    // Initialize response.
    response.reset(); // Some JSF component library or some Filter might have set some headers in the buffer beforehand. We want to get rid of them, else it may collide.
    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); // Check http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types for all types. Use if necessary ServletContext#getMimeType() for auto-detection based on filename.
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"name.pdf\""); // The Save As popup magic is done here. You can give it any filename you want, this only won't work in MSIE, it will use current request URL as filename instead.

    // Write file to response.
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    output.write(pdfData);
    output.close();

    // Inform JSF to not take the response in hands.
    facesContext.responseComplete(); // Important! Else JSF will attempt to render the response which obviously will fail since it's already written with a file and closed.
}
```

Desde html solo necesitarais un link a la página que genera el contenido a partir del arreglo de bytes, en este caso un pdf.

El código es de ejemplo, talvez te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hago eso mismo que me sugeristes. No se que hice mal entonces.

Comment: Sale este error Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[co.staffing.backendstaffingapp.servlet.AccesoServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet co.staffing.backendstaffingapp.servlet.AccesoServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException